# Salesforce trigger to update a field based on a picklist value on a visualforce page

Tags: triggers, insert, salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to find a way to have a trigger update a picklist field based on a picklist selection from another field.  I want the trigger to update on the insert of the record.

For example, I have a field called Address__c that is a picklist field and I want the trigger to select the appropriate location based on the address selected.

Address_*c 123 Main Street selected, updates Location*_c "Main St."
Address_*c 321 Elm Street selected, updates Location*_c "Elm St"

I've done an extensive search on this topic but haven't found anything that will update a picklist field from a picklist.   Any suggestions?

Comment: Might need a bit more info on your data model. Are the `Address__c` and `Location__c` fields on the same object? Or is `Location__c` a lookup to another object, and you want to update the address on that based on the value of `Address__c`?

Comment: Location__c is not a lookup field, it is a picklist field.  I'm trying to get the field to update automatically on the VF page after the selection is made on the Location__c picklist.

Comment: Alright, there should be a variety of options depending on your circumstances. Any chance you can post some of the code that you've been trying?